# Passing through undefined variables with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function to numerically integrate with NIntegrate. This function can be written mathematically as

$$ F(a,b,c,y,z) = \sum_i a^i b^j c^k f_{ijk}(y,z)$$

where $a,b,c$ are undefined variable (i.e. constant ) and $f_{ijk}(y,z)$ are function depending on the integration variables $y,z$.

I want to integrate $F(a,b,c,y,z)$ doing something like

```
NIntegrate[F[a,b,c,y,z],{y,0,1},{z,0,1}]
```

without assign any numerical value to $a,b,c$ ( I know that NIntegrate gives an error if $a,b,c$ have not numerical values) . I did it manually, that is I just integrated separately the functions $f_{ijk}(y,z)$ and then I reconstructed the final function of $a,b,c$ but I would like to do it quicker.

Answer (score 2):

It is always useful to provide a simple example. Here is an example of your function:

```
SeedRandom[0];
F = Total[Times @@@ (Power[{a,b,c,y,z}^#]& /@ RandomInteger[5, {10,5}])]
```

> a^4 b c^2 y+a^5 b^3 c^4 y+a^3 b^3 c^4 y^2+a^5 b y^4+a^5 y z+a^5 b^4 c^4 y z+a^2 b c^2 y^3 z+a^4 b^5 c^5 y^2 z^2+a^4 b c^2 y^5 z^2+a^4 b c^3 z^3

One applicable function is [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html):

```
Collect[F,{a,b,c},NIntegrate[#,{y,0,1},{z,0,1}]&]
(* expand if you desire *)
Expand @ %
```

> 0.125 a^2 b c^2+0.333333 a^3 b^3 c^4+a^5 (0.25 +0.2 b+0.5 b^3 c^4+0.25 b^4 c^4)+a^4 (0.111111 b^5 c^5+b (0.555556 c^2+0.25 c^3))
>
> 0.25 a^5+0.2 a^5 b+0.125 a^2 b c^2+0.555556 a^4 b c^2+0.25 a^4 b c^3+0.333333 a^3 b^3 c^4+0.5 a^5 b^3 c^4+0.25 a^5 b^4 c^4+0.111111 a^4 b^5 c^5

Another idea is to use [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html) and [`FromCoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCoefficientRules.html):

```
(* get exponent -> coefficient rules *)
rules = CoefficientRules[F, {a, b, c}];

(* use NIntegrate on coefficients *)
rules[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules[[All, 2]], {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}];

(* reconstruct polynomial *)
FromCoefficientRules[rules, {a,b,c}]
```

> 0.25 a^5+0.2 a^5 b+0.125 a^2 b c^2+0.555556 a^4 b c^2+0.25 a^4 b c^3+0.333333 a^3 b^3 c^4+0.5 a^5 b^3 c^4+0.25 a^5 b^4 c^4+0.111111 a^4 b^5 c^5